# How to fit label "css width"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set the width of some labels exactly fitting the label words. If I just use something like this:

```
<label style="background-color:red;">test label</label>
```

That works, but I want to use bootstrap to make the website responsive, so when I add:

```
<label style="background-color:red;" class="col-xs-4">test span</label>
```

The label width grows,and I need it to be just as long as the word it display, for example in the picture you can see the difference, I'm coloring red the label background to know which is the width, I woould like to reach something like `test label` is displayed, but using bootstrap too.

[image]

I've set this code :

```
<label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-bottom:100px; display:inline; width:0;" id="lblAviation">Aviation</label>
```

getting this result:

[image]

But as you see the background is not fitting the first letter of the word, is more to the left, what do I need to improve?

UPDATE: This is all my code:

```
<div style="height:400px; width:600px" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="height:100px">

            <img src="~/images/aviation.png" width="80" height="80" id="aviation" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="height:100px">
            <img src="~/images/international.png" width="80" height="80" id="imgInternational" class="jumper" />
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:1em">
            <label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-bottom:100px; display:inline-block; width:0;" id="lblAviation">Aviation</label>

            <label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-bottom:100px; margin-left:250px; display:inline; width:0px;" id="lblInternational">International</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="height:100px">

            <img src="~/images/longshore3.gif" width="80" height="80" id="imgLongshore" class="jumper" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="height:100px">
            <img src="~/images/marine.png" width="80" height="80" id="imgMarine" class="jumper" />
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:1em">
            <label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="height:100px; margin-left:80px;" id="lblLongshore">Longshore</label>

            <label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" style="height:100px; margin-left:120px" id="lblMarine">Marine</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:inline; width:auto;`? What responsiveness you think you will hain by adding `class="col-xs-4"`?

Comment: What was the issue with your original label?

Comment: I think you might be overthinking your issue. You don't need to add Bootstrap column classes to every element to make them responsive. It's hard to determine the exact layout you're aiming for as you've only provided a label and not associated form inputs. Additional markup would be useful.

Comment: just add display: inline-block to your label and set a percentage

Comment: @hungerstar I've updated my question, I've been working in other issue and now I've come back to this one

Comment: @AlexGH could you also include a simple mockup of the desired layout? Also, what is the intended purpose of the content/markup?

Comment: @hungerstar this code fixed it: `<label class="col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-bottom:100px; margin-left:110px; display:inline; width:auto;" id="lblAviation">Aviation</label>`

Comment: @hungerstar if you have any suggestion or advice about design that would be welcome :)

Comment: @Oriol you were right :), if you post your comment as answer I can give you the point, and if you have any suggestion or advice should be helpful too. With this code I could reach my goal: `<label class="col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-bottom:100px; margin-left:110px; display:inline; width:auto;" id="lblAviation">Aviation</label>`

Comment: At first glance there's issues with how you're using the Bootstrap grid - you have have rows and columns as siblings. Column elements should be child elements of row elements. You probably should use another element instead of `<label>` as it's used for forms. This doesn't look like a form. The inline styling is not ideal (basically a no-no), but you might have been planning to change that later. Based on very minimal information I'd do something [along these lines](https://jsfiddle.net/w4rzrLno/).

Comment: @hungerstar thanks a lot man, I'll try your dessign. thanks for your help I'm not an expert on bootstrap :)

Comment: @hungerstar Your dessign is awesome, I think it's very constructive and helpful even if I already asked Oriol to post his comment as answer to select it,  if you want you can post an answer with your code and at least I will give you the point and would be helpful to others :)

Comment: Can't you just do this? `<label class="col-xs-4"><span style="background-color:red;" >test span</span></label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you code is

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
#lblAviation {
  display: inline;
  width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" id="lblAviation">Aviation</label>
```

There are some problems with that:

- Inline elements ignore the `width` property. Using `display: inline` and `width` together is useless.
- `.col-xs-4` sets `float: left`, which blockifies to `display: block` (and thus `width` is respected after all). Using `display: inline` and `float` together is useless.
- Except in some special layout modes or when you use `min-width`, `width: 0` will make the element ignore its contents and be 0px wide. Usually that's undesired.

If what you want is make it ignore `.col-xs-4`'s `width: 33.33333333%` and let it shrink-to-fit, what you should set is the initial `width: auto`.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
#lblAviation {
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2" id="lblAviation">Aviation</label>
```